# ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_39_input to have shape (6,) but got array with shape (1,)

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, neural-network, sklearn-pandas

This is my first post in stackoverflow.
So I have built a Neural Network predicting AirBnb prices , with accuracy 77 % but I am struggling to input an array so the model can give me a prediction. (Jupyter Notebook)

```
xa = np.array([3, 1, 1, 28, 1, 1])
print(xa.shape)
(6,)

ynew = nn3.predict(xa[0:1])
print(ynew)
```

and  after line 5 the error is appearing

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_39_input to have shape (6,) but got array with shape (1,)
```

With ynew = nn3.predict(xa) I have the same error.

Thank you!

Comment: Why the [0:1]? Did you use 6 arguments when you built the network?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
xa = numpy.array([[3, 1, 1, 28, 1, 1]])
ynew = nn3.predict(xa)
print(ynew)
```